# Как отключить автоматические отступы в VS Code python

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

У меня есть некоторый код, который представлен в виде класса и нескольких методов.

```
class BookAdminForm(ModelForm):

    MIN_RESOLUTION = (300, 400)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['cover'].help_text = f'Изображение должно иметь минимальное разрешение 300x400'

    def clean_image(self):
        image = self.cleaned_data['cover']
        img = Image.open(image)
        min_width, min_height = self.MIN_RESOLUTION
        print(min_width, min_height)
        if img.height < min_height or img.width < min_width:
            raise ValidationError('Разрешение загруженного изображения меньше минимального!')
        return image
```

Однако стоит мне сохранить файл, то VS Code автоматически делает лишний отступ в методе. Получается то, что у меня метод clean_image входит в конструктор, и он не работает. Как это исправить?

```
class BookAdminForm(ModelForm):

    MIN_RESOLUTION = (300, 400)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['cover'].help_text = f'Изображение должно иметь минимальное разрешение 300x400'

        def clean_image(self):
            image = self.cleaned_data['cover']
            img = Image.open(image)
            min_width, min_height = self.MIN_RESOLUTION
            print(min_width, min_height)
            if img.height < min_height or img.width < min_width:
                raise ValidationError('Разрешение загруженного изображения меньше минимального!')
            return image
```

Comment: первый вопрос а что у Вас установлено в качестве автокорректора? Там есть несколько разных версий, и `clean_image`  он имхо ставит правильно.. а почему не переносит константу и `__init__` если уж следит за отступами.. P.S. Вы же понимаете что в первом примере у Вас ошибка как раз в отступах?

Comment: @Kers , видимо не так скопировался код из VS Code. Исправил на то, что у меня было. У меня стоял pylint, насколько я помню.

Comment: @Kers Он второй метод табулировал в первый.

Comment: Pylint это линтер что в принципе немного другое. У Вас должно быть что-то типа pep8, yapf, black. В общем то идея сменить форматер и посомтреть останется ли ошибка. и тогда копать или в настройках VSC или форматтера.

Comment: Откройте настройки VSC и вверху в строке поиска введите `Python › Formatting: Provider`, переключите на другой и проверьте наличие ошибки. У меня воспроизвести Вашу ошибку так и не получилось. Есть еще вариант сбросить настройки VSCode. но уже крайний вариант.